# Как создать массив размером BigInteger?

Tags: java, массивы, biginteger

Необходимо создать массив, размер которого берется из массива BigInteger.

Так не хочет, в квадратных скобках требует `int`:

```
BigInteger[] NewArr = new BigInteger[bigIntegerArr[0]];
```

Comment: А `[bigIntegerArr[0].intValue()]`? Если, конечно, значение меньше `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Вроде бы, максимальный размер массива Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8, то есть, нет смысла пытаться задавать его bigInteger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Максимальный размер массива Integer.MAX_VALUE, так что никак. Можно только создать свою структуру, где будут храниться массивы в массивах и написать к ним итератор.